# Is there a way to restrict access to push upgrades?

Tags: managed-package, profile, push-upgrade

I'm trying to restrict access to push upgrades functionality in the org to certain user profile.

I'd like to create a developer profile, which allow users to create, upload and test package, but restrict access to Push Updates.

According to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/push_upgrade_scheduling.htm permission “Upload AppExchange Packages” is required. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, the developer user is still able to push upgrades even if the permission is disabled.

The only solution I've found is to disable also “Create AppExchange Packages”, but this disallows creating new version of the package.

Is there a way to allow a user to upload packages but prevent him from pushing upgrades?